# Count two values (total words & uniques) in multiple files (texts) and output a csv in Python

Tags: python, text

I work with various collections of text files, about which I want to know a variety of things, like word counts, etc. I have code that successfully does this, and now I want to introduce a script into my workflow that will work its way through a directory and compile statistics on the text files in there.

Here's my draft:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# Get from each text file a total word count and a unique word count.
# Output a CSV with three columns: filename, total, unique.

import glob

with open (file_name) as f, open ('countfile.csv', 'w') as out :
    list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.txt)
    for file_name in list_of_files:

        ???

        out.write('{f},{t},{u}\n'.format(f =file_name, t =word_total, u =uniques)
```

The question marks above are a placeholder for what I want to do with each file, which is the code below:

```
# Total No. of Words        
word_list = re.split('\s+', textfile.read().lower())
word_total = len(word_list)

# Unique Words
freq_dic = {}
punctuation = re.compile(r'[.?!,":;]') 
for word in word_list:
    # remove punctuation marks
    word = punctuation.sub("", word)
    # form dictionary
    try: 
        freq_dic[word] += 1
    except: 
        freq_dic[word] = 1

uniques = len(freq_dic)
```

I don't quite know how to insert all of this code into the code above. I somehow suspect that that won't work, but I'm at a loss on how to proceed. Any help here would be much appreciated. If I can figure this out, then I think I might be really able to automate quite a few things.

I know the second block of code is perhaps not the prettiest, but it's about as compact as I could get it and still understand what it was doing. As you can no doubt tell, I'm early on in my learning of Python.

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:

What I have is a directory of texts:

```
text1.txt  
text2.txt  
text3.txt
```

What I want is to point this script at that directory and have it go through all the texts and output a CSV file with the following form:

```
text1, 345, 123
text2, 1025, 318
text3, 765, 245
```

(Sheering off the `.txt` of the filename is not necessary, mind.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
files = {}
for fpath in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(fpath) as f:
         fixed_text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z'-]"," ",f.read())
    words = fixed_text.split()
    total_words = len(words)
    total_unique = len(set(words))
    files[fpath] = (total_words, total_unique)
    print "Total words:", total_words
    print "Total unique:", total_unique

with open("some_csv.csv", "w") as f:
    for fname in files:
        print >> f, "%s,%s,%s" % (fname, files[fname][0], files[fname][1])
```

I think that should work ...

Comment: Thanks, Joran. I edited the question to make the task more clear. My apologies for leaving that part out!

Comment: I'm getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on `with open("wordstats.csv") as f` with the caret pointing to `f`. Any ideas?

Comment: whoops .. you need to open it for "w"riting (see edit) (also needed a `:`)

Comment: Hmmm ... it doesn't like the asterisk in `print >> f , "%s,%s,%s"%(fname,*files[fname])`. Could you also explain how that's working? I had expected a more literal series of substitutions, you're doing something really interesting here, but I don't know how to parse it.

Comment: got rid of the unpacking (the asterisk) ...  not sure what you are asking with the rest of that comment ...  but its just reading them in and storing them in a dictionary (a list would have worked just as well) and then just dumping them out to a file ...

Comment: Once I remembered to make sure that I had `import glob, re` at the top of the script, it worked nicely. Thanks! I look forward to playing around with this and learning!